# Pythonic way to filter a DataFrame based on dates example

Tags: python, pandas

```
In [90]: list_dates = [datetime.date(2014,2,2),datetime.date(2015,2,2), datetime.date(2013,4,5)]

In [91]: df = DataFrame(list_dates, columns=['Date'])

In [92]: df
Out[92]: 
         Date
0  2014-02-02
1  2015-02-02
2  2013-04-05
```

Now I want to get a new DataFrame with only the dates that are from years 2014 and 2013:

```
In [93]: result = DataFrame([date for date in df.Date if date.year in (2014,2013)])

In [94]: result
Out[94]: 
            0
0  2014-02-02
1  2013-04-05
```

That works and gives me the desired DataFrame.
Why doesn't the following work:

```
In [95]: result1 = df[df.Date.map(lambda x: x.year) == 2014 or p.Date.map(lambda x: x.year) == 2013]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-95-86f01906c89b> in <module>()
----> 1 result1 = df[df.Date.map(lambda x: x.year) == 2014 or p.Date.map(lambda x: x.year) == 2013]

/home/marcos/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.pyc in __nonzero__(self)
    690         raise ValueError("The truth value of a {0} is ambiguous. "
    691                          "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."
--> 692                          .format(self.__class__.__name__))
    693 
    694     __bool__ = __nonzero__

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Or the following:

```
In [96]: df['year'] = df.Date.map(lambda x: x.year)

In [97]:     result2 = df[df.year in (2014, 2013)]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-97-814358a4edff> in <module>()
----> 1 result2 = df[df.year in (2014, 2013)]

/home/marcos/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.pyc in __nonzero__(self)
    690         raise ValueError("The truth value of a {0} is ambiguous. "
    691                          "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."
--> 692                          .format(self.__class__.__name__))
    693 
    694     __bool__ = __nonzero__

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I think that the problem is that when I use the 'in' command I am trying to check if a whole Series is in a tuple. But how do I make the evaluation be elementwise so that I get the result I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd convert the dates to datetime objects using [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html#pandas.to_datetime), this then allows you to use the [`dt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#datetimelike-properties) accessor to access the `year` attribute and we can then call [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html#pandas.Series.isin) and pass a list of years of interest to filter the df:

```
In [68]:

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
In [69]:

df[df['Date'].dt.year.isin([2013,2014])]
Out[69]:
        Date
0 2014-02-02
2 2013-04-05
```

Comment: When I run the commands again together with your suggestion I get:
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'dt'



I ran:
In [118]: list_dates = [datetime.date(2014,2,2),datetime.date(2015,2,2), datetime.date(2013,4,5)]

In [119]: df = DataFrame(list_dates, columns=['Date'])

In [120]: df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

In [121]: df[df['Date'].dt.year.isin([2013,2014])]

Comment: You must be using an older version of pandas, what version are you using? Can you upgrade?

Comment: In [123]: pd.__version__
Out[123]: '0.14.1'

Comment: This was added in `0.15.0` can you upgrade?